# Remove elements from array

Tags: php, arrays

For example I have array:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
```

How can I remove `('a', 'b', 'c')` from the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unset](http://php.net/unset) will remove them:

```
unset($arr[0], $arr[1], $arr[2]);
```

And there is [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice):

```
array_slice($arr, 3);
```

Returns:

```
array('d', 'e', 'f')
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this.  The optimal really depends on your input.

If you have an array of the values you need to remove, which is probably your case, this will work best:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$bad = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$good = array_diff($arr, $bad); //returns array('d', 'e', 'f');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$remove = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$arr = array_diff($arr, $remove);
```