# Remove all items of an array except the last 5 on PHP

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove elements from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823236/remove-elements-from-array)

how would I remove all array elements but last 5 ones? The array is a log, but the log will become extensive so I just want to see the five recent items (a.k.a. last five elements)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$a5 = array_slice($arr, -5);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$new = array_slice($old, -5)
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are getting this array from the text file, you shouldn't read the whole file into array.

either use a command line utility to get 5 last lines,

```
$last5 = `tail $logfile`;
```

or at least read only last chunk of it, of considerable side of, say 1Kb and than get last 5 out of it.

Comment: You mean `$last10` probably and mind [parameter injection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).